# Regular expression matching range(x, y)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

WTmatch number range `[0-9]+`, end match at '-' and ',' and put resulting numbers into array.

I have something like `'^([0-9]+)'` but I don't know how to end the match at a certain character and to start a new match.

Here is my code. It will take an input like 88-367, possibly incorrect, in which case I want to construct a list of all numbers separated by arbitrary values, and return a range (88/#1, 367/#2)

wondering if interpreter will run teh input in the lambda correctly to return a formatted string that contains the arguments of range (is this even possible in python?)

Best

```
import re

def main():
        pages = [i for i in range(command=lambda : re.match(input("Print number range in format '#+-#+': ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear by showing us some sample inputs along with what you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you  `^([0-9]+)[-,]`

`[-,]` is a class, it means match a single character of which one is in the class.